# Why PhpStorm doesn't show my class?

Tags: php, class, methods, phpstorm, code-hinting

I created a class like this:

```
class FOO {

        public function __construct(){}

        public function getArr(){}

}

$x=new FOO(); //don't show "FOO" suggestions
$x-> //don't show suggestions
```

The problem is that PhpStorm doesn't show me the suggestions to my class in the "new" statement and if I create in instance of `FOO` it doesn't show me the `FOO` methods...

I don't know if it is a problem of PhpStorm; I have imported the Facebook php sdk class and it give the correct hints to me...

**UPDATE:**

I think I have found the problem:

-if I have opened a project and I import the file with the class (that is outside from the project directory, drag & drop into the IDE) to quick edit it, the IDE don't give me the suggestions

-instead, if I open the single file Itself and have no others projects opened the IDE works correct

Comment: 1) Please try `File | Invalidate Caches...` and restart IDE. Any better? 2) If you give it another name (e.g. `Foo2`) -- will it do any different? 3) If still nothing -- please post screenhots (of the whole IDE window) where such problem exists.

Comment: I just testet - it does. Did you start your file with "<?php" so phpStorm knows it's php code?

Comment: I have updated the post @LazyOne

Comment: @Francesco Yes -- that's expected behaviour (limitation(?) of their system). The file MUST be inside the project to have code completion properly working there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @LazyOne, the answer is that the behavior is correct from the moment that I opened the file from outsite the project where I were working on.

> if I have opened a project and I import the file with the class (that
>   is outside from the project directory, drag & drop into the IDE) to
>   quick edit it, the IDE don't give me the suggestions

---

> Yes -- that's expected behaviour (limitation(?) of their system). The
>   file MUST be inside the project to have code completion properly
>   working there.